# Re-use autoenrolment CSR to obtain another certificate

Tags: active-directory

It's about Windows ADCS.

The problem: we want to get S/MIME certificates from external vendor, but the local law obligates us to keep encryption keys so we can decrypt any company data in case of any investigation.

We figured that we can create an autoenrolment template for S/MIME that would use key escrow, so that the private key is stored in safe location, and the re-use the same CSR to obtain S/MIME certificate from the vendor.

The only problem is: how to extract request's CSR from the CA database?

Comment: I do believe, this question fits StackOverflow, not Information Security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ICertView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certview/nn-certview-icertview) COM interface to query `Request.RawRequest` column from CA database for required request. You will get request in a PKCS#10 or PKCS#7/CMC format.

Comment: Yes, it does. `Connect-CA | Get-IssuedRequest -RequestID $ID -Property "Request.RawRequest"`

Answer (score 2):

You can export the request from the Certification Authority MMC if you add the **Binary Request** column to the **Issued Certificates** view.

Once you've done that, right click on your issued certificate and choose **All Tasks** > **Export Binary Data...**.  From that dialogue, select **Binary Request** from the dropdown menu and ensure the **Save binary data to file** radio button is selected.  Click **OK** and you'll be prompted to save the file.  Save it and send it to the external CA.